# getting related row value in codeigniter using ajax and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

There is one table in my database named 'paper' which consists of id, title and value columns. I have populated the tables with some title and values. Right now I have,

```
id     title     value
1       x          20
2       y          30
3       z          35
```

I have fetched all the titles column from paper table table and displayed it in a dropdown in my view. Now, what i want is, when i select the title from the dropdown (e.g y), I want to display its corresponding value (e.g 30) side by side in the same view. I am new to ajax and jquery.. I will be really glad if somebody provides me a solution.

Comment: http://www.91weblessons.com/codeigniter-ajax-country-state-city-drop-down/ check this link

Comment: You'll need to look at a Restful server for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already fetching the `title` column you might as well fetch the `value` column as well and just display it with some jQuery, something like:

```
<select id="title-select">
  <option value="" selected>Choose a title</option>
  <option value="20">x</option>
  <option value="30">y</option>
  <option value="35">z</option>
</select>
<span id="value-display"></span>

<script>
$('#title-select').on('change', function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $('#value-display').html(val);
});
</script>
```

Example - http://codepen.io/adampuddlemedia/pen/wBJejY